# Internal Server Error when trying to run flask

Tags: python, html, flask

I am trying to create a website with a web form in it using flask, but I keep getting an Internal Server error, despite getting no error when I run it in the console

Here is my code:

__init.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from forms import TestForm

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_pyfile('config.py')

@app.route('/')
def homepage():
    return render_template("main.html", form=TestForm())



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

forms.py

```
from flask_wtf import Form
from wtforms import StringField, BooleanField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired

class TestForm(Form):
    test_form = StringField('test_form', validators=[DataRequired()])
```

config.py

```
WTF_CSRF_ENABLED = True
SECRET_KEY = '<super-secret>'
```

main.html

```
<DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Sample Page</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"
    initial=scale=1/>
    <link href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{{ url_for('static', filename='favicon.ico') }}" rel="shortcut icon">
</head>
<h2>Hello, this site is meant to test my fill_web_form.py script</h2>
<br>
<br>
<h1>Test Form</h1>
<form action="/" method="post" name="login">
      {{ render_field(form.test_form(size=80) }}<br>
      <p><input type="submit" value="Sign In"></p>
 </form>
</html>
```

When I run `flask run` I get this

```
$ flask run
  * Serving Flask app "FlaskApp"
  * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

When I try to access `http://127.0.0.1:5000/` in both chrome and firefox I get an error, but I feel like that's a whole separate question.

Comment: Well, what is the internal server error? Is there a stack trace?

Comment: No, it just says "The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application."

Comment: Yes, but doesn't your Python console have any output? Try turning on debug mode.

Comment: It is on debug mode, there is no error when I run it in the console, the bottom of my question shows the output from `flask run`

Comment: Maybe your port 5000 is blocked. Have you tried 8080?

Answer (score 1):

If all of your codes are here then I can tell you the problem might be about rendering form, try this one (`pip install flask-bootstrap`):

```
# __init.py
...
bootstrap = Bootstrap(app)
```

main.html

```
{% import 'bootstrap/wtf.html' as wtf %}
...
{{ wtf.quick_form(form) }}
...
```

Comment: I was able to get that code to work, now I have this problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40816625/why-am-i-getting-a-500-error-when-trying-to-connecto-to-an-sqlite-database