# Why am I getting a 500 error when trying to connecto to an sqlite database?

Tags: python, html, sqlite, flask

I trying to make a site that passes data from a web form to an `sqlite` database. I keep getting a 500 error. When I type the ip address and get to main.html, it displays the page with no errors, but when I submit the form I get a 500 error.

It doesn't give me the stacktrace is just says `The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.`

It's hard to debug this because when I access the server through a browser, it doesn't give me details about the error. And when I run `flask run` in putty, it doesn't give me an error, it just gives me this [image]
searching http://127.0.0.1 in my browser doesn't work, I'm guessing because flask run is running on the server and not on my computer.

Here is my code:

__init__.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from forms import TestForm
import sqlite3

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def homepage():
    return render_template("main.html", form=TestForm())

@app.route('/post', methods=['POST'])
def post():
    conn = sqlite3.connect("sample.db")//If I remove these two lines
    conn.close()                       //The code works without error
    return render_template("test.html")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

forms.py

```
from flask_wtf import Form
from wtforms import StringField, BooleanField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired

class TestForm(Form):
    test_form = StringField('test_form', validators=[DataRequired()])
```

main.html

```
<DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Sample Page</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"
    initial=scale=1/>
    <link href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{{ url_for('static', filename='favicon.ico') }}" rel="shortcut icon">

</head>
<h2>Hello, this site is meant to test my fill_web_form.py script</h2>
<br>
<br>
<h1>Test Form</h1>
<form action="/post" method="post" name="test">
    {{ form.test_form(size=80) }}
    <p>Form</p><br>
      <p><input type="submit" value="Test Form"></p>
 </form>
</html>
```

test.html

```
<DOCTYPE html>
</html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Testing 123</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do `export FLASK_DEBUG=1` before `flask run`.

Comment: Now it just says "Debugger is active" and gives me a pin code

Comment: And when you post the form? You should get a nice traceback in the browser.

Comment: It says ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED when I try to connect to 127.0.0.1 in Chrome. This is what I'm confused about though. If I'm running flask run on my server, wouldn't that mean that 127.0.0.1 for my server is different than 127.0.0.1 for my computer? so accessing 127.0.0.1 from my computer would be useless.

Comment: did you ever try `sqlite` directly in Python Shell ? Open Python and run `import sqlite3` and `conn = sqlite3.connect("sample.db")`. Maybe it has problem to create file "sample.db" in folder - it may need some privilages in folder. Or simply you have to install `sqlite` C/C++ library (in Windows it means `.dll` files): https://sqlite.org/

Comment: It works in the shell.

Comment: did it create `"sample.db"` ? Do you have `"sample.db"` in project folder ? Remove it. Maybe it is wrong formatted file and `sqlite` can't it open.

Comment: Yes it created it, I deleted the file and still got the error, and then reran the python shell commands to recreate it and still got the error. Thanks for helping btw

Comment: you can put `conn = ...` and `conn.close()` instead of `app.run()` and run your script again. Maybe it shows some error with more information.

Comment: If you run the flask app on the same computer that you open the browser in, go to 127.0.0.1. Otherwise go to the IP address of the server.

Comment: @furas That didn't change anything

Comment: @AlexHall I tried going the IP of the server, but I don't get any output in the putty terminal

Comment: Did it display any error message when you run script in console ?

Comment: Stop any flask that is running, open putty terminal *on your server*, set `FLASK_DEBUG=1`, run flask on the server, it must say "Debugger active", go to the IP address of the server in your browser, post the form, check for output in the terminal, and verify that you're really using only the server by also visiting 127.0.0.1 and getting connection refused.

Comment: @AlexHall Ok, did that, got the same error and connection was refused when I visited 127.0.0.1

Comment: Did it show "Debugger active" in the server terminal output but nothing else useful?

Comment: @AlexHall It said "Debugger is active" then "Debugger pin code" and a number

Comment: And when you post the form? Do you get a 500 error in the browser but nothing else helpful in either the browser or the terminal?

Comment: @AlexHall Yes that's exactly what happens

Comment: This is really weird. Kill the flask process in your terminal and refresh in the browser. Do you now get a connection error?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129101/discussion-between-matt-d-and-alex-hall).